# Passing Data from SettingsView Controller to Mainstoryboard - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, settings

I am a newbie to iOS app development trying to build a tip calculator. The basic functioning of the app is completed. My Mainstoryboard has a segment control which shows three % values such as 10, 20, 30. There is a Settings button which on click takes me to a new page and shows the similar % values in a segment control.

What I want to do is that, when a number is clicked (a segment) it should be saved as the default tip% value. How should I pass this value to the Mainstoryboard function where I have written a function to calculate the tip amount?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using a segue for moving to the other view, so use prepareForSegue method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "tipSegue"
    {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? OtherViewController {
            destinationVC.tipPercent = someValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used the below line and the value is not getting passed:

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showSettings"{
            let settingsVC:SettingsViewController = segue.destination as! SettingsViewController
            settingsVC.delegate = self
}
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `protocol` for setting the default percentage, and have your `MainViewController` conform to that protocol.  When a user taps a button in your `SettingsViewController` you can call a function (defined within the protocol) to let the "delegate" (MainViewController) know what has happened, and set your `default` variable accordingly.  If this is a permanent setting it might be better to use `UserDefaults`, as this is exactly what that was designed for.  Then, upon loading `MainViewController` you can access that `UserDefaults` variable, if it exists.

A little protocol help:

Your protocol could be defined very simply - something like this (and this has to be declared outside of your viewControllers - I often do it above the class declaration of a related viewController):

```
protocol SettingsDelegate {
    func didUpdateDefaultTipPercent(to percent: Float)
}
```

That's it for the protocol declaration, unless you anticipate needing other functions.  Note that you don't actually define the functionality of that function - each viewController that conforms to the protocol may have a different definition of that.

Then, in your settingsViewController you might have an optional variable for protocol conformer like this:

```
weak var settingsDelegate: SettingsDelegate?
```

and after the user chooses a default percentage you can safely check to see if the delegate exists and pass that new number to the delegate like so:

```
if let delegate = self.settingsDelegate {
    delegate.didUpdateDefaultTipPercent(to: 15.0) //this "15.0" will come from your segmented control action or whatever
}
```

In your `MainViewController`, in your `prepareFor(segue...` you will need to check to see if you are going to settings, and set `Main` as the delegate:

```
...
if let settings = segue.destination as? SettingsViewController {
    settings.settingsDelegate = self
}
```

And, finally, you'll need to make your `MainViewController` conform to the protocol.  I usually do this as an extension just to make it easier to find, and to keep it separated from other things:

```
extension MainViewController: SettingsDelegate {
    func didUpdateDefaultTipPercent(to percent: Float) {
        self.defaultPercentage = percent
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes I am trying to use UserDefaults. However I don't know how to use protocols and delegates. Any help?

Comment: @NinjaCowgirl OK, I added the full implementation in my edit.  See above.  Ultimately, if this is a permanent setting, UserDefaults is the way to go.  In that case you don't really need the protocol, but it is an incredibly valuable thing to understand and be able to implement.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will check this out.